How to compute different central products $Z_n \circ_\theta Z_m$ when $\theta$ change?
Recently, I learned the concept of central product:
Definition: Let $H$ and $K$ be groups. If there exist subgroups $H_1$, $K_1$ such that $H_1 \le Z(H)$, $K_1 \le Z(K)$ and isomorphism $\theta: H_1 \rightarrow K_1$, then we can construct (external) central product,
${H \circ_\theta K}:= \frac{H \times K}{N}$ where $N:=\{(h,k) \in H_1 \times K_1 \mid \theta(h) \cdot k = 1\}$.
A lot of information shows that the isomorphism type of ${H \circ_\theta K}$ may change, as $\theta$ vary in $\mathrm{Isom}(H_1,K_1)$. I want to find a simple example such the above situation happen.
Let the above $H = Z_n = \left\langle x \right\rangle , K = Z_m = \left\langle y \right\rangle$ $(n, m \in Z^+)$, $d = \gcd(n,m)$. Let the above $H_1$ and $K_1$ be the unique subgroup of $H_1$ and $K_1$ of order $d$ respectively. If we choose $\theta$ such that $\theta(x^{n/d}) = y^{m/d}$, then we can derive that ${H \circ_\theta K} \cong Z_{mn/d}$ (My proof is written below). But I don't know what will happen if we choose $\theta$ such that $\theta(x^{n/d}) = y^{tm/d}$ $(g.c.d(t,d)=1)$. Will ${H \circ_\theta K}$ have different isomorphism type?
Proof as $\theta(x^{n/d}) = y^{m/d}$:
(Lemma 1): Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two sets of generators, $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two sets of relations of $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively, then $\left\langle S_1 \mid R_1 \right\rangle \times \left\langle S_2 \mid R_2 \right\rangle \cong \left\langle S_1, S_2 \mid R_1, R_2, \left[ S_1, S_2 \right]  \right\rangle$.
(Lemma 2): Let $S$ be a set of generators, $R_1, R_2$ two sets of relations of $S$, then $\left\langle S \mid R_1, R_2 \right\rangle \cong \left\langle S \mid R_1 \right\rangle /ncl(\overline{R_2})$.
Using the above lemma, we can obtain a presentation of ${H \circ_\theta K} = \frac{H \times K}{N} \cong \left\langle x,y \mid x^n=y^m=1, xy=yx, x^{n/d} = y^{m/d} \right\rangle$. Construct a homomorphism $f: \left\langle x,y \mid x^n=y^m=1, xy=yx, x^{n/d} = y^{m/d} \right\rangle \rightarrow Z_{nm/d}$ such that $f(x)=\overline{m/d}$ and $f(y)=\overline{n/d}$. It's easy to verify that $f$ is well-defined and isomorphic.$\Box$
Thought: I think this method may not be useful for general $\theta$, because $n/d$ and $tm/d$ may not be comprime, so it's hard to verify that $f$ is surjective.
I'm not familiar with central product and my English is not good...I would appreciate any help.

Your claim about $H\circ_{\theta} K$ is incorrect. Just take $d=1$; or take $n=m$ and $d\lt n$, in which case $H\circ_{\theta}K$ must have exponent $n$ (being a quotient of $H\times k$, but $Z_{mn/d}$ has exponent strictly larger than $n$.

@ArturoMagidin I am so sorry... I left out one important condition, $d = g.c.d(n,m)$. Let me revise my question and recheck my proof.

Yes, it's an error (and you explicitly said $d$ was just "a positive common divisor"). But in this case you will just get the cyclic group no matter what $\theta$ you choose.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you very much for your help! I don't quite know how to construct an isomorphism onto $Z_{nm/d}$ when $\theta(x^{n/d})=y^{tm/d}$ where $g.c.d(t,d)=1$.

I've gone ahead and given a proof central product of two cyclic groups only depends on the subgroups we are identifying, and not on the isomorphism chosen.

@ArturoMagidin Yeah, I saw it! Thank you! I think most of difficulties are centered on number theory and I need more practice. Again, I sincerely thank you for your help!

Here's a proof that a central product of two cyclic groups is independent of the choice of isomorphism $\theta$ between their identified subgroups. It does not rely on the resulting group being cyclic.
Theorem. Let $H=\langle x\mid x^m=1\rangle$, $K=\langle y\mid y^n=1\rangle$, let $d$ by any common divisor of $m$ and $n$, and write $m=ad$, $n=bd$. Let $\theta\colon\langle x^a\rangle\to \langle y^b\rangle$ be an isomorphism. Then the isomorphism type of the central product $H\circ_{\theta}K$ is independent of the choice of isomorphism $\theta$.
Proof. Let $t$ be such that $\theta(x^a) = y^{tb}$, with $\gcd(t,d)=1$.
We first show that there exists $u$ such that $\gcd(u,n)=1$ and $ub\equiv tb\pmod{n}$.
By Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, from $\gcd(t,d)=1$ we conclude that the arithmetic progression $t+\alpha d$ contains infinitely many primes. Pick $\alpha$ so that $u=t+\alpha d$ is a prime greater than $n$. Then $\gcd(u,n)=1$, and $u\equiv t\pmod{d}$. Multiplying through by $b$ we get $ub\equiv tb\pmod{n}$.
Now note that $y^u$ is a generator for $K$, and that $(y^u)^b = y^{ub} = y^{tb}$. Thus, replacing $y$ with $y^{u}$ (via an automorphism of $H\times K$ induced by this automorphism of $K$), we conclude that $H\circ_{\theta}K = H\times_{x^a=y^b}K$, so the isomorphism type of $H\circ_{\theta} K$ does not depend on the choice of isomorphism $\langle x^a\rangle\cong \langle y^b\rangle$. $\Box$
